# Name Dataframes after list values

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to create 3 dataframes, and name them after the 2nd element of each list.

In my actual project, there are 10+ dataframes, and the number could vary.

I don't know how to structure the return statement in the function. I also believe that when I state `x[1] = pd.DataFrame()`, I am inadvertently attempting to change the list value, whereas my intention is to use the list value as the df name itself.

```
import pandas as pd

names = [
    ['SPtab', 'sp', 'man'],
    ['SBtab', 'sb', 'man'],
    ['SDtab', 'sd', 'man']
]

def create_dfs():
    for x in names:
        x[1] = pd.DataFrame()
    return
    
print(sp)
print(sb)
print(sd)
```

Comment: this is considered an anti pattern - creating dynamic global variables. Use a container like a dictionary. `dfs = {x[1] : pd.DataFrame(x) for x in names}`

Comment: This makes sense. But once I do this, how do extract each dataframe from the dict so that it can be referenced, like with the print statements I included?   And, is there any reason why I can't use the 'names' list as the container, and just add the df as a 4th element to each list?   thank you

Comment: `print(dfs['sb'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (using dynamic global variables is a bad practice and it would be better if you use a python dictionary, this solution uses dynamic variables. The lower one uses a dictionary):

```
import pandas as pd

names = [
    ['SPtab', 'sp', 'man'],
    ['SBtab', 'sb', 'man'],
    ['SDtab', 'sd', 'man']
]

def create_dfs():
    for x in names:
        exec(f"%s = pd.DataFrame()" % (x[1]), globals())
    
create_dfs()
```

`create_dfs()` creates several empty variables with the names defined in `names`. It uses the built in `exec()` function to define a variable with the name defined in the `names` list. When `exec()` is called, it is called with `globals()` as a parameter to make sure that the variable is a global variable.

Or you could do it with a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

names = [
    ['SPtab', 'sp', 'man'],
    ['SBtab', 'sb', 'man'],
    ['SDtab', 'sd', 'man']
]

def create_dfs(names):
    dfs = {}
    for x in names:
        dfs[x[1]] = pd.DataFrame()
    return dfs
    
dfs = create_dfs(names)
```

For this solution `create_dfs()` returns a dictionary containing all of the dataframes. This output is assigned to a variable called `dfs`